# C program to read data from USB device connected to the system

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to fetch data from the USB device (say pendrive) connected to the USB port of a system. Here, I am able to open the device file and read some random raw data. But I want  to fetch data like minicom/teraterm.

Please let me know what methods and libraries I can use to do it successfully and how can it be done.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include <errno.h>   
#include <termios.h> 
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
    short portfd=-1;
    int n,f,len;
    char buf[256],*s;
    alarm(2);
#if defined(O_NDELAY) && defined(F_SETFL)
    portfd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR|O_NDELAY);
    if (portfd >= 0){
        /* Cancel the O_NDELAY flag. */
        printf("port openend\n");
        n = fcntl(portfd, F_GETFL, 0);
        (void) fcntl(portfd, F_SETFL, n & ~O_NDELAY);
    }
#else
    portfd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
#endif
    if (portfd >= 0) 
    {
        if (len == 0) len = strlen(s);
        for(f = 0; f < len && f <100; f++)
            buf[f] = *s++ | 0x80;
        write(portfd, buf, f);
        printf("Do write\n");
        while(portfd>=0){
            printf("%s\n",buf);
        }
    }

    alarm(0);
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
    if (portfd < 0) {
        printf("cannot open %s. Sorry.\n", "/dev/ttyUSB0");
    }
}
```

Log of the output:

```
���������鉀�������������������鍀���������������������������������������������������������������2
����������鉀�������������������鍀���������������������������������������������������������������2
```

Comment: Have you checked out [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/)? And if the connected device is a pendrive, and it's mounted into the filesystem, then read the files normally from it.

Comment: I tried to include it, but its throwing error as 'No such file' for #include <libusb.h>

Comment: which distro ? if under debian like have you installed the libusb-dev package ? aka `apt get install libusb-dev`

Comment: There is no need for `libusb` or any other third-party library, `/dev/ttyUSB*` is a mere serial line which is handled directly by the kernel. The only thing required is to correctly configure the serial parameters (speed, parity, ...) as with any other serial line.

Comment: @user2818819 A pen drive is a very different thing from a serial line. /dev/ttyUSB0 is an USB serial line. Different USB devices have _very_ different means of operating. For a simple serial line, there's numerous tutorials - they work the same whether it's an USB serial line, or an old RS232. What are you actually trying to do and what kind of device have you connected ?

Comment: its actually VNC2 eval board. And it is detected as ttyUSB0 in my system.

Comment: I shouldn't have used "write(portfd, buf, f)" as I am reading from the ttyUSB0. So I used read(), 'read(portfd, buf, f)'. But after executing I'm getting blank screen

Comment: @syam As u suggested, I configured the serial parameters as follows. But still I'm getting junk values 
t = tcsetattr(portfd, TCSANOW, &options);tcgetattr(portfd, &options); cfsetispeed(&options,B9600);cfsetospeed(&options,B9600);
options.c_cflag |=(CLOCAL | CREAD);options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; options.c_cflag &=~CSTOPB;options.c_cflag &= CSIZE;options.c_cflag |= CS8;   
options.c_cflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE |ISIG );
options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY );options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;tcsetattr(portfd, TCSANOW, &options);
options.c_lflag &= 0;
options.c_iflag &= 0; 
options.c_oflag &= 0;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need to set the correct port configuration...

```
struct termios oldtio,newtio;

// open port...
// save existing attributes
tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio);  

// set attributes - these flags may change for your device
#define BAUDRATE B9600 
memset(&newtio, 0x00, sizeof(newtio));  
newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;   
newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;          
newtio.c_oflag = 0;  

tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);  
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio); 

//reset attributes
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
```

I have a rough working example here... http://file-hub.com/cmd:thread/142300